# simple css stylish printing woes

Tags: css, printing

I am trying to "engineer" a cover page in html+css that shows appropriately in browsers, fits exactly on the (A4) page, and prints it with background colors.  no javascript---it has to go to epub2.  I am enclosing my first attempt at a prototype.  (the actual cover page will of course be more complex.)

the bad news is that it's already not working.  the worse news is that it's not working differently in firefox and chromium under linux---and I have not even tried safari, IE, OSX, iOS, Android, and Windows yet.

I am not averse to starting over, as long as I can remain in the html+css paradigm (i.e., I don't want to have to create a png bit image in TeX if it can be avoided.).

can this be done?  or is it time to go back to TeX?  advice appreciated.

regards,

/iaw

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>

<style type="text/css">

body {
    color: #EEFFEE;
    font-weight: bold;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
    width: 21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
    background-color: yellow !important;
    color:black;
}

@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 0;
}
@media print {
    .page {
    margin: 0;
    page-break-after: always;
    }
}

<!-- breaks color:  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; -->

div.mytitle {
  color:red;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align:center;
}

</style>

</head>


<body>

<div class="page">

  <div class="mytitle">

    <div style="margin:auto;font-size:100px;">Title</div>

    subtitle
  </div>

  text

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start with a reset stylesheet. It'll help with some browser differences.

Comment: What's the exact question? FYI, printing background color is typically a end-user setting/preference (as it can waste a lot of ink)

Comment: exact question: is it possible to css-design this simple one-A4 web page that will print in the same fashion from all browsers and OS's, and that has a centered title in white in front of a blue background at the top of the page?

Answer (score 0):

So in tinkering with your code if you move the -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; to end of style it works for me in chrome ie and firefox. You can throw the code in http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/ will see that it works as long as the line sits underneath your other rules. Hope it helps.

Will